# How to enter and leave an existing screen through script?

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen

I'm fairly new with Linux shell scripting but have several years experience using Linux(non-hardcore).

There is an application running on my server(accessing it through SSH/putty) which is a console one. In order to ensure that it will run even even if I close my ssh client(putty), I made it run though screen.

In my script, there is a part where I want to enter this specific screen and "leave a message", then leave the screen to proceed with other things it have to perform.

How to do it exactly? Thanks!

(the console application is actually a vanilla Minecraft server)

Answer (score 0):

check out 'screen' window manager http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ with session names, see the following article:

http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/a-quick-tutorial-on-screen/

Comment: Yes, I'm already using screen. However, my question is about making a bash script that will open the screen and enter a command string then leave the said screen.